# Incorrect output using WEKA's MultilayerPerceptron in text classification

Tags: java, neural-network, deep-learning, weka

I have been trying to use a MultilayerPerceptron neural network in order to classify my data. However, with whatever configuration tried, I always seem to get the same results, as shown below, of only 50% correct. I can confirm that other classifiers seem to provide more believable results using the same dataset.

My data is of the format 'string, nominal'.

To explain pre-processing a bit more - I am using the StringToWordVector filter to convert the string to attributes in my data set (this gives me about 1000 attributes). My class attribute is a nominal one, of either positive or negative.

When attempting to cross-validate the neural network on 4000 (2000 per class) of these instances, I get the same results repeatedly. What exactly is causing the network to point everything to a single class?

[Cross-validation output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ4rw.png)

[Dataset configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEdwF.png)

[Network configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiHlC.png)

Comment: please add more details and  sample code

Comment: This is currently being done with the WEKA explorer, so no code required currently. Once I have a working configuration in the Explorer, I will correct my code for it. My latest configuration and dataset are described in the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer to this, I found that I had to increase the number of neurons in the hidden layer. I got improved results changing this to 100 and in changing it to 'the number of attributes', it is not all being mapped to a single class (the original issue).